# Default resampling method in mlr3

Tags: mlr3

If I did not mention any resampling methods in my mlr3 code, what happens in the background? Does it run a default resampling method? If yes, what is it? k-fold CV?

Comment: You really always have to specify a resampling method, unless you're using code that already defines one. `mlr3` predefines some, but you always have to explicitly use them. There's no default, just like there's no default learner or dataset.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, if there is no default, then how it works ? In the mlr3 book, there are a lot of examples which did not mention any resampling methods. The examples even did not divide the data into train/test splits.

Comment: Those examples use a resampling method that's defined earlier in the book. There is no default. Without specifying a resampling, you can only do the things that do not require a resampling, e.g. train a model.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Read the documentation at https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com
2. Run code yourself and inspect the resampling object